# ArrayList errors program won't run

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

Ok so I'm very very new to java. I'm trying to complete homework for a class but I'm stuck. I keep getting errors about my arrayLists in the main so it won't run and don't know why or how to fix it. The errors say "Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0" and "The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments ". Someone in my class already suggested changing something called compliance which tried but then it started saying that there was no main in my code even though clearly there was. I'm using the Eclipse on our school citrix server. Hoping you guys can help me solve the problem so I can run the code. Please help me. The website won't let me post a screenshot of the errors but it's on these lines....

```
ArrayList<Double>priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> quantityList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> amountList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

this is the program description.....

Write a program called ThreeArrayLists.java that declares three ArrayList objects referenced by the objects named priceList, quantityList, and amountList. Each ArrayList should be declared inmain() and should be capable of holding a minimum of 10 double-precision numbers.
   The numbers that should be stored in priceList are 10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98 .
   The numbers that should be stored in quantityList are 4, 8.5, 6, 7.35, 9, 15.3, 3, 5.4, 2.9 4.8.
   Your program should pass object references to these three ArrayList objects to a method named extend(), which should calculate the elements in the amountListArrayList as the product of the corresponding elements in the priceList and quantityListArrayList, for example, amountList.add(priceList.get(i) * quantityList.get(i)).
   Afterextend() has put values into the amountListArrayList object, create a method that displays the results of all three lists. Appropriate formatting techniques need to be used to produce a formatted output.

...and below is the complete code.

```
package week6;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ThreeArrayLists extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static String result;

public ThreeArrayLists() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ProceTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    QuantityTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    CalculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    ResultTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("ThreeArrayLists");

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14));
    jLabel1.setText("ThreeArrayLists");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel2.setText("priceList:");

    ProceTextField.setEditable(false);
    ProceTextField.setText("{ 10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98 }");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); 
    jLabel3.setText("quantityList:");

    QuantityTextField.setEditable(false);
    QuantityTextField.setText("{ 10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98 }");

    CalculateButton.setText("Calculate");
    CalculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CalculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
    jLabel4.setText("amountList:");

    ResultTextArea.setColumns(20);
    ResultTextArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ResultTextArea);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 361, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 287, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(QuantityTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ProceTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 9, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGap(46, 46, 46))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(235, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(CalculateButton)
            .addGap(199, 199, 199))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(208, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(194, 194, 194))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(ProceTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(QuantityTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(CalculateButton)
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 195, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}

private void CalculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ResultTextArea.setText(result);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
double[] PRICE_ARRAY = { 10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98 };
double[] QUANTITY_ARRAY = { 4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8 };
ArrayList<Double>priceList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> quantityList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> amountList = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    priceList.add(new Double(PRICE_ARRAY[i]));
    quantityList.add(new Double(QUANTITY_ARRAY[i]));
}

result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    amountList.add((Double.valueOf(priceList.get(i).toString())) * (Double.valueOf(quantityList.get(i).toString())));
    result += String.valueOf(i+1) + ")  "
           + new String(df.format(priceList.get(i))) + " * "
           + new String(df.format(quantityList.get(i))) + " = "
           + new String(df.format(amountList.get(i))) + "\n";
}
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ThreeArrayLists().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JButton CalculateButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField ProceTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField QuantityTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextArea ResultTextArea;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
```

}

Comment: Which JDK version and which JRE version are you using? Maybe there consists a mismatch of some type.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419226/eclipse-syntax-error-parameterized-types-are-only-if-source-level-is-1-5

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the JDK you are using may be below version 1.5, Generics weren't introduced until Java 5.

You could try declaring your lists like so:

```
ArrayList priceList = new ArrayList();
```

Then you need to remember to cast to `Double` when referencing elements if you want to manipulate the data later on.

Answer (score 0):

**Java** with version *below* 1.5 doesn't handle generic types ( aka types parametrized by other types: List ).

To run your code in **Java** 1.4 you need to loose the generic type parameter and do the casts yourself. Bellow is a way how to achieve something similar to your objective.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {
    String result;


     double[] PRICE_ARRAY = { 10.62, 14.89, 13.21, 16.55, 18.62, 9.47, 6.58, 18.32, 12.15, 3.98 };
     double[] QUANTITY_ARRAY = { 4.0, 8.5, 6.0, 7.35, 9.0, 15.3, 3.0, 5.4, 2.9, 4.8 };
     ArrayList priceList = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList quantityList = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList amountList = new ArrayList();
     public void homework(){ 

         for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
             this.priceList.add((Double)(PRICE_ARRAY[i]));
             this.quantityList.add((Double)(QUANTITY_ARRAY[i]));
             this.amountList.add((Double)priceList.get(i) * (Double)quantityList.get(i));
         }

     }
     public void output(){
         System.out.println("Price list: " + priceList.toString());
         System.out.println("Quantity list: " + quantityList.toString());
         System.out.println("Amount list: " + amountList.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok tried doing it this way but i got different errors. This way the ArrayList part woks but then I get errors on "this" saying "cannot use this in a static context" and late in those lines for "Double" errors saying "cannot cast from double to Double".

Comment: I have tried this code and it worked for me. With regards to the error when using "this" - "this" refers to instance members and static method will only access static variables. Which line does throw an error saying cannot cast from double to Double? You can try parsing primitive double to object Double please refer to this website : http://www.java-examples.com/convert-java-double-double-object-example