# Neomades Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Tags: java, neomad

I've created a neomad project as a test project to run unit test based on code from my main neomad application project.  The issue that I'm running into is that I encounter errors like the following:

Syntax error, static imports are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

I've changed the java build configuration to 1.8, however I still get the same type of errors. Is it that what I'm trying to do is not possible with neomad because it transpiles Java into other languages?

```
 import com.neomades.app.Application;
    import com.neomades.app.Controller;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
    import org.junit.runner.Result;
    import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;


    /**
    * Entry point
    */
public class UnitTestsApp extends Application {

    public void onStart(Controller controller) {
        // first screen
        controller.pushScreen(UnitTestsScreen.class);


        controller.runOnBackgroundThread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {

                List<Class> testCases = new ArrayList();

                //Add test cases
                testCases.add(JSONConverterTests.class);

                JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
                core.addListener(new TestRunListener());

                for (Class testCase : testCases)
                   {
                        RunTestCase(testCase);
                   }
            }

        });
    }


    private static void RunTestCase(Class testCase)
    {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(testCase);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try by cleaning your project

Comment: @khan thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it's still complaining.

Comment: have you configure new 1.8 JRE properly? please check with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419226/eclipse-syntax-error-parameterized-types-are-only-if-source-level-is-1-5

Comment: Yes, 1.8 JRE is properly configured. I'm able to successfully build other project with JRE.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it that what I'm trying to do is not possible with neomad because it transpiles Java into other languages?

Unfortunately, yes.

NeoMAD 3 only supports Java 3, which means JDK level 1.3.

NeoMAD 4, which will be released Q2 2016, will introduce the support for Java 5. This will unlock many cool Java features such as generics or static imports.

But at the moment, you must keep the jdk compliance level to 1.3 in Eclipse.