# Annotation are only available for java 1.5 and greater when generating Google App Engine Backend(JDK 1.8, new ADT installed)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I installed fresh ADT: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk
Then I installed:

[image]

When I got into the Eclipse readme directory there is:

> Eclipse Project Release Notes
>
> Release 4.3.0 Last revised May 29th, 2013

I created fresh Android application then right clicked on it->Google->Generate Google App Engine Backend and this is what I got:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The import android.os.Build is never used   MainActivity.java   /A/src/com/uniquebullshit/a line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageData.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 22 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 21 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageData.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 28 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 21 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageData.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 29 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar is never used   MainActivity.java   /A/src/com/uniquebullshit/a line 4  Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfo.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 25 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfo.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 46 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 46 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 98 Java Problem
The method setMaxResults(int) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)   MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 95 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 112    Java Problem
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater    MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 105    Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 127    Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 126    Java Problem
The method listDeviceInfo(String, Integer) in the type DeviceInfoEndpoint is not applicable for the arguments (null, int)   MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 142    Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 142    Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 74 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 73 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 76 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 75 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 77 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 76 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 81 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 77 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 140    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to DeviceInfo DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 143    Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 119    Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 139    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to DeviceInfo DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 154    Java Problem
There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiConfigException: class com.uniquebullshit.a.MessageEndpoint has no @Api annotation.   A-AppEngine     Unknown Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Problem Marker
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to DeviceInfo    MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 144    Java Problem
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater    MessageEndpoint.java    /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 144    Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 33 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 34 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 31 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 32 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 35 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 39 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 34 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 35 Java Problem
Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater    DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 60 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 65 Java Problem
The method setMaxResults(int) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)   DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 54 Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to DeviceInfo DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 82 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 97 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 77 Java Problem
Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater  DeviceInfoEndpoint.java /A-AppEngine/src/com/uniquebullshit/a   line 78 Java Problem
```

**How to deal with that?**
EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I tried below and it helped.

1. Tick the checkbox named `Use default compliance settings` as in highlighted section (blue color) of image below.
2. If that didn't help, try changing the `Compiler compliance level` to different level, press apply and then back again.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me **Enable Project Specific Settings** check box was not selected. I selected it and clean the project through **Project** menu.

Answer (score 2):

The answer mentioned by Stultuske in [[eclipse magic: ... Syntax error, varargs are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736730/eclipse-magic-are-only-available-if-source-level-is-1-5-yesterday-everythi][1]) solved it.

Under Mac OS X

- Install the Java 6 JDK
- Goto Eclipse > Preferences
- Select Add... from Java > Installed JREs then Standard VM and select the '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home' directory as the JRE home, then Finish, Ok

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem.

I checked the Java JDK version under "Java Build Path".

I checked the compliance levels under "Java Compiler".

I looked at Project Facets and saw that Java wasn't checked. Checking it resolved the problem (once the project rebuilt).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure the source level is 1.5 or above. it seems you are using an older version of the JDK.

Comment: I have newest JDK 1.8.

Comment: should work then. in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736730/eclipse-magic-are-only-available-if-source-level-is-1-5-yesterday-everythi
it looks like sometimes, you need to build using JDK 6 (odd to say the least) in order to avoid this issue with a higher version.
haven't encountered it myself though, so 'm not talking out of personal experience here.

Comment: Did it nothing, changed ; /

Comment: This:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1736779/199364  Project Settings / Set `Compiler compliance level` to 1.5 or more.